# Transfer photos from my iPhone wirelessly

Tags: mac, iphone

I want to transfer photos off of my iPhone 4 without plugging it into my Mac. What's the best way to do this (the best option I see now is to email the photos to myself 5 at a time)?

Comment: Question protected. It's had no fewer than *three* spam answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) account, you can upload photos to that and it will automatically sync with any computers you have that are also running Dropbox.

Comment: I think he means from his phone onto his computer.

Comment: Yeah. You can upload photos from the iPhone to the Dropbox, and they will automatically sync to all computers also using Dropbox.

Comment: Dropbox would be ideal, but you can only transfer 1 photo at a time

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I was on the train with no cable of internet connection,

turn bluetooth on your iphone in your setting on the home screen of your iphone,

then turn bluetooth on on your mac,

you can do this by going system preferences > bluetooth i think

or to make it easier [go to this page](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=383506) which tells you how to activate bluetooth on a mac

then pair the devices which you find out how to do it one [this page](http://www.oreillynet.com/wireless/2002/08/13/bluetooth_osx.html)

and away you go, share your pics

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Answer (score 0):

Check out WifiPhoto and [QuickPic](http://quickpicapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Photosync.

First install Photosync for iOS from [Here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosync-wirelessly-transfers/id415850124?mt=8)

Then go to [this site](http://www.photosync-app.com/) to download free version on computer, works on both Mac and Windows.